# Google Location API отдает неточные координаты

Tags: android, google-maps-api

Всем привет, пишу приложение для отображения ближайших ресторанов, для получения местоположения пользователя использую Google Maps Location API, для получения ресторанов использую Foursquare API, маркеры ресторанов на карте ставятся корректно, а вот местоположение пользователя - с погрешностью, и причем с большой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На третьем скриншоте синим квадратом помечено где я точно нахожусь, как видите, погрешность высокая, вчера маркер стоял там, сегодня - не там, почему так?

В `onCreate` я создаю `FusedLocationProviderClient` и `GoogleApiClient`:

```
locationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .build();
```

Вот методы интерфейса `GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks`:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    updateLocation();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    googleApiClient.connect();
}
```

Вот метод `updateLocation`:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"MissingPermission"})
@OnClick(R.id.searchRestaurantsFab)
public void updateLocation() {
    locationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
            if (location == null) {
                showToast(R.string.enable_gps);
            } else if (mapIsReady) {
                mapsFragment.showMyLocation(location);
                updateRestaurants(location);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: что-то какие-то маленькие скриншоты. ничего не видно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, в каком всмысле маленькие? Довольно-таки большие

Comment: @iFr0z, ответы - в ответы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы получить точное местоположение (координаты) нужно [подключить](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest) По всем источникам (gps, internet, wi-fi, bluetooth).

---

На самом деле все просто.

```
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
Location mCurrentLocation;
double mLatitude = 0, mLongitude = 0;
...

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest().setInterval(1).setFastestInterval(1).setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY); // по всем источникам
    mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper()) // запрос на обновление местоположения
    updateLocation();
}    

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

LocationCallback mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
            mCurrentLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();
            if (mCurrentLocation == null) new LatLng(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(), mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()); //без слежки
        }
};
```

Comment: я реализовал так: при получении координат отписываюсь от обновлений, когда надо - его запускаю, спасибо

Comment: @Flippy рад был помочь :)